# How to create Filament resource for models inside a vendor folder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament

To begin, I am using Filament to create an admin panel where the admin can create Topics, Questions, and Answers for quizzes. Meanwhile, for the quizzes, I am using this package https://github.com/harishdurga/laravel-quiz. The package contains models and relationships for topics, questions, question options, etc.

Now, to create a Filament resource, the command is `php artisan make:filament-resource Customer`. This will create a Filament resource for `App\Models\Customer.php`. However in my case, I want to create this Filament resource for the models from the package, which are inside the vendor folder.

How do I create the resource and reference it to the models inside the vendor folder?

The file structure to reach the models in the package is:

> vendor/harishdurga/laravel-quiz/src/Models/Question.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify in Filament CustomerResource which model to use, for example :

```
public static $model = Customer::class;
```

Documentation for it :
https://filamentphp.com/docs/1.x/admin/resources

Comment: oh i didn't notice that! but LaravelDaily suggested that I create a Customer model and extends it to the Customer model from the package though. thank you

Comment: Sorry, i think instead of public property it is `protected static ?string $model` property

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new model and extend it from the one you have in the vendor. There you already create the resource.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some sample code to demonstrate your answer is significantly different than the accepted answer?